# template specialization round-lambda notation

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T, class I> struct A;  //EDIT:    template <class T> struct A; : OK

template <class T, class I>
struct A<T(I)>
{

};


void main()
{
    A< int(char) > b;
}
```

This code doesn't compile. WHere is the mistake ?
THanks

Comment: I hope A< int(char) > b will call the specialization form of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T> struct A; and no template <class T,class I> struct A;
```

sorry to answer myself but perhaps that will useful for other users

Comment: No need to apologize, it is perfectly OK to answer your own question.